# Python - MySQL table join

Tags: python, mysql

Im trying to outer joins on multiple tables within a python query.

(outer join because some fields have null data)

Im using the following:

```
sql = "SELECT \
  CATINFO.Chip_ID AS Cat, \
  CATDIET.Diet_Req AS Diet, \
  CATMEDICAL.Med_his AS Med\
  FROM CATINFO \
  OUTER JOIN CATDIET, CATREQ, CATMEDICAL ON CATINFO.ID = CATDIET.Chip_ID, CATREQ.Chip_ID, CATMEDICAL.Chip_ID"
```

i get the following error output:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000):
'OUTER JOIN CATDIET, CATREQ, CATMEDICAL ON CATINFO.Chip_ID = CATDIET.Chip_ID, CATREQ.Chip_ID, CATMEDICAL.Chip_ID'
```

Im not sure exactly where ive gone wrong.

the idented table format should be like the following example:

```
Chip_ID   diet         req           med 
1         low carb     null          broken leg
2         null         belly rubs    null
```

Comment: Can you add how would you like the table will look like?

Comment: Your are trying to use old-school join syntax merged with modern join syntax. That's a recipe for disaster. Provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: ' If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html , AND you would normally indicate the direction of an outer joins either left or right (most often left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sql = "SELECT \
  CATINFO.Chip_ID AS Cat, \
  CATDIET.Diet_Req AS Diet, \
  CATMEDICAL.Med_his AS Med, \
  CATREQ.Add_Req AS Req \
  FROM CATINFO \
  LEFT JOIN CATDIET ON CATINFO.Chip_ID = CATDIET.Chip_ID \
  LEFT JOIN CATMEDICAL ON CATINFO.Chip_ID = CATMEDICAL.Chip_ID \
  LEFT JOIN CATREQ ON CATINFO.Chip_ID = CATREQ.chip_ID "
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the column names (since you don't mention them clearly). Proper outer joins are written this way:

```
select
  i.chip_id as cat_id,
  d.diet_req as diet,
  r.req_name as req,
  m.med_his as med
from catinfo i
left join catdiet d on d.chip_id = i.id
left join catmedical m on m.chip_id = i.id
left join catreq r on r.chip_id = i.id
```

Change column names, as needed.

Comment: Yeah my apologies i presumed i put enough information in the question but i thought wrong, after changing the formatting of your answer i got it to work. Thanks dude